# approximate fisher information for intractable likelihoods

Tags: approximation, fisher-information, intractable-likelihood

Suppose I have a data set $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, and from that I compute a statistic $T(X_1, \ldots, X_n) := T$. I want to assess how reactive/sensitive this calculation is to changes in parameter values. My first instinct is to use [Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information).

I have the likelihood of the data, and I can simulate the data, so I can simulate many $T$s. However, I want to be able to calculate this for $T$s that have pretty crazy formulas. These formulas are nontrivial to program, and they're probably going to be impossible to get a likelihood for.

So, proceeding under the assumption that the likelihood for $T$ is intractable, how can we get an approximation of the Fisher Information (matrix elements) for $T$:
$$
[\mathcal{I}_T(\theta)]_{ij} = -\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta_i \partial \theta_j} \log L(T ; \theta)\right]?
$$
I could use Monte Carlo if I could evaluate derivatives of the log-likelihood, but I have no ideas about how to circumvent that. Does anyone know of any work that's been done on this?